# AngularJS: How to get index value in ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

I am new is angularjs and i am trying to get the index value in `ng-repeat` means i want to set `md-option` value as index value my code is:

```
<md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
    <label>Filterable Columns</label>
        <md-select ng-model="visualization.filterable_columns" ng-change="drawFilters()" multiple="true" ng-init="index = 1">
            <md-option ng-repeat="filterable_column in vm.filterable_columns" value="{{index++}}">
                {{filterable_column.label}
            </md-option>
        </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

can anyone help me about this?

Comment: Warning: Using `$index` may not be advisable, q.v. [here](https://www.codementor.io/angularjs/tutorial/angular-best-practices-ng-repeats-index).

Comment: is there any another way..please !!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you can try like this:

```
<md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
    <label>Filterable Columns</label>
        <md-select ng-model="visualization.filterable_columns" ng-change="drawFilters()" multiple="true">
            <md-option ng-repeat="filterable_column in vm.filterable_columns" ng-value="{{$index}}">
                {{filterable_column.label}}
            </md-option>
        </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

Answer (score 11):

Add **track by $index** to your **ng-repeat**

```
<md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
   <label>Filterable Columns</label>
   <md-select ng-model="visualization.filterable_columns" ng-change="drawFilters()" multiple="true">
      <md-option ng-repeat="filterable_column in vm.filterable_columns track by $index" ng-value="{{$index}}">
         {{filterable_column.label}}
      </md-option>
   </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the helper function;

```
$scope.getIndexOf=function(arr, val, prop) {
      var l = arr.length,
        k = 0;
      for (k = 0; k < l; k = k + 1) {
        if (arr[k][prop] === val) {
          return k;
        }
      }
      return false;
    };
```

Example is;

```
$scope.Index=function(){
$scope.getIndexOf(vm.filterable_columns,"{{filterable_column.label}}","filterable_column.label")
};
```

You call this function in md-option's ng-change event. like this;

```
<md-select ng-model="visualization.filterable_columns" ng-change="drawFilters(); getIndexOf(vm.filterable_columns, {{filterable_column.label}}, filterable_column.label) " multiple="true" ng-init="index = 1">
           <md-option ng-repeat="filterable_column in vm.filterable_columns" value="{{index++}}">
                                 {{filterable_column.label}}
            </md-option>
      </md-select>
```